# Vue.js Iterating over properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Problem overview:

I'm trying to learn some Vue.js, and I quickly ran into a use case I can't wrap my head around (yay!)

I'm trying to create a Vuejs table component. The looks like the following:

```
<template>
  <div class="mytr">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.id">
        {{header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
      <td>{{todo.title}}</td>
      <td>{{todo.completed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Tablerow',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: ['title', 'completed'],
      todos: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/').then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.todos = data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using the api from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/).

The question is: can this be written with a syntax similar to the following:

```
<tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
  <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header.id">
    {{todo.header}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This would allow me to specify the columns I want to print from my data making this component more portable and usable.

Please forgive me if the question is too basic. I have o-kay pure JS background, Python/Django, and the rest is fairly low level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each `header` is a string, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property of `todo`

```
<tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
  <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header.id">
    {{todo[header]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! In Vue, would `[header]` be called a property, a member, or is the language consistent as if we're referring to JSON objects and call them values and keys?

Comment: Yes. You can add any valid javascript expression within `{{ }}` and it will be evaluated